# List content files in a windows phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my wp7 app, I include a bunch of data files which are set as Content. In my app, I want to bind them (they are all in a common Data folder in the app) to a list box so the list box shows the names of the content files. However, I cannot find a way to list file names. Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: See the "almost-duplicate": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456609/how-to-enumerate-images-included-as-content-in-the-xap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a public API on this. WP7 is meant to store everything in Isolated Storage.

Comment: You could, however just store all the files in IsolatedStorage, and use `IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); storage.GetFileNames()` (and `storage.GetDirectoryNames()`)

Comment: @willmel but he'd have to know a list of the files to move to IsolatedStorage and I think the point of the question is to avoid having to list all the files in code.

Comment: Thanks! I can workaround that by listing the files in the code directly.