# Coping files from desktop to Windows Phone 7 Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to Phone 7 development.

I am trying to create an application the will load all the DLLs that I have created from a set location on the phone.

I have a basic menu application that will load all the DLLs I have created and display a list of then to the user using reflection to get an Icon out of the DLL and a description.

I have the following code to get all the dll but its not working

```
Dim cPlugins As New PluginCollection
        Dim temp As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName().CodeBase.ToString
        temp = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName
        Dim strFolder As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(temp)
        strFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(strFolder, "DLLS")

        For Each strFile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFolder, "*.dll")
            cPlugins.Add(New Plugin(strFile))
        Next
```

The above code doesn't work and keeps returning a file not found error.

Any help please?

Comment: Is this running on the phone?

Comment: it falls over on the line `Dim temp As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName().CodeBase.ToString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the DLLs as resources you'll need to add them as embedded resources (build action) in the projet/XAP file.

This will not require you to copy them to isolated storage.

If you were copying them to isolated storage then you could put htem there with isolated storage explorer but this would only work for testing. For the live app you'd need to include them in the XAP and then copy them to isolated storage. As you don't neeed them in isolated storage to open them as resources to extract images then it would be unnecessary effort.

If possible, you coudl make things easier for yourself in the WP7 app by not embedding the images inside a DLL but this may not be practical if you are using the same images/DLLs across projects on multiple platforms. Even if this is the case I'd recommend considering adding a build step to you WP7 app to extract the images once at design time. This will mean your app has to do less. It will therefore able to be faster, have less opportunity for bugs and provide a better experience to the user.

**Edit:**
The issue is the way you are trying to query the files in IsolatedStorage. There is no need to calculate the actual path of your isolated storage location. Instead you should use the [IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190395%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). You'll use it like:

```
Using store As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    .... store.GetFileNames("/DLLS/*.dll")
End Using
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that but it still doesn't really sort my problem, I have set the build action to Content, as I can have my DLLs as resources so these dlls can change (the end plan is to have newer versions downloaded from a web server). When ever my application hits the line  `Dim temp As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName().CodeBase.ToString ` the application stops and the Exception isn't show

Comment: You are right, if you're going to update them then having them in the XAP won't help.

Comment: is there any other way to find that applications Installation location other than using `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName().CodeBase.ToString` ?

Comment: Thanks for that but Am I just being a prat as when I use you code I keep getting Directory doesn't exist

Comment: You can test for a directory existing using the DirectoryExists method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.directoryexists(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: Do I need to create the Directory in IsolatedStorage and copy the dlls in to that folder? as there is no files or directories in my IsolatedStorage

Comment: How have you copied hte files to Isolated Storage? If you didn't put them there then they won't be there. It's the only way to get a file to isolated storage. If you are just including them as content as part of the XAP/project then they won't be there. There's an example of copying files from the xap to isolated storage at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I think we are getting away from what am asking.   How do I get a list of all the files that I have set as build Action Content?

Comment: You were asking how to get files out of isolated storage when you hadn't even put anything there. You may find this useful: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Understanding-Isolated-Storage

Comment: how can I move a list of files to Isolated Storage with out having to list all the files in code? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671957/list-content-files-in-a-windows-phone-7-app[link] I have come across this and its a similar problem to mine.

Answer (score 0):

The property `Codebase` isn't supported in Silverilght on the Phone. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=VS.95).aspx) but you don't need to use this method to find the isolated storage location. Use the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class instead.

Comment: Thanks for you help Guys, I got around me problem but having the application download all my DLLs from a webservice straight into Isolated storage on start up. So I can then get a list of them and show this list to the user.