# How to enumerate images included as "Content" in the XAP?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, resources

I'm including a number of images as "Content" in my deployed XAP for Mango.

I'd like to enumerate these at runtime - is there any way to do this?

I've tried enumerating resources like:

```
foreach (string key in Application.Current.Resources.Keys)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Resource:" + key);
}
```

But the images aren't included in the list. I've also tried using embedded resources instead - but that didn't help. I can read the streams using `Application.GetResourceStream(uri)` but obviously I need to know the names in order to do this.

Comment: Could you clarify the purpose for doing this?

Comment: In this particular case, they are approx a hundred icons that I want to precache in memory. I don't know, but I suspect this will help with a performance issue I'm seeing. In a previous case (an offshoot of iron7), I wanted to load up a directory full of ruby scripts on startup. In both cases, I could hardcode the lists in C#, but I'd rather avoid this if there is a way - it would be great if I could just enumerate whatever gets added to the folder)

Comment: I don't think you'll gain any notable performance increment from "pre-loading" them. Having a build-type to content should be speedy enough. At least it is for all my apps.

Comment: Understood - it's one of several things I'm trying. Regardless, would still be interested in knowing how to do this - although it doesn't look like it is really supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enumerate the files set as "Content".

However, there is a way to enumerate files at runtime, if you set your files as "Embedded Resource".

Here is how you can do this:

1. Set the Build Action of your images as "Embedded Resource".
2. Use `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` to
   enumerate the resources names
3. Use
   `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resName)`
   to get the file streams.

Here is the code:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        foreach (String resName in GetResourcesNames())
        {
            Stream s = GetStreamFromEmbeddedResource(resName);
        }
    }

    string[] GetResourcesNames()
    {
        return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
    }

    Stream GetStreamFromEmbeddedResource(string resName)
    {
        return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resName);
    }
```

EDIT : As quetzalcoatl noted, the drawback of this solution is that images are embedded in the DLL, so if you a high volume of images, the app load time might take a hit.

Comment: Yeah, but you have forgotten to tell the OA that the thing you suggest has one big negative impact: EmbeddedResource causes the files to get EMBEDDED into the resulting DLL. With "Content", they would be put as normal files along with the DLL. Thus, if you turn large volume of files into "EmbeddedResource" - your DLL will significantly grow and startup time will suffer. The point of using "Content" is make the module smaller! While there's no way to enumerate the "content" on WP7 due to security restrictions, it is possible to generate a list during build process and read the list in runtime.

Comment: That's right, I edited the answer to highlight that drawback.

Answer (score 4):

This is no API baked in to WP7 that allows you to enumerate the contents of the Xap.  You need to know the name of the content items before you can retreive them.

There probably is some code floating around somewhere that is able to sniff out the Zip catalog in the XAP however I would strongly recommend that you don't bother.  Instead include some sensible resource such as an Xml file or `ResourceDictionary` that lists them.

Answer (score 4):

Having found no practical way to read the Content files from a XAP I build such a list at design time using T4.

See an example at https://github.com/mrlacey/phonegap-wp7/blob/master/WP7Gap/WP7Gap/MainPage.xaml.cs

This seems the right way to go as:
a) I'd rather build the list once at design time rather than on every phone which needs the code.
and
b) I shouldn't ever be building the XAP without being certain about what files I'm including anyway.

Plus it's a manual step to set the build action on all such files so adding a manual step to "Run Custom Tool" once for each build isn't an issue for me.