# How can I get a list of all embedded resources defined in my application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, resources

How to get a list of all files (e.g. images) embedded as resources or content programmatically?

I tried

```
ResourceDictionary res = Application.Current.Resources;
```

But this does not return any files.

Answer (score 2):

If the resources have build action **Content** then there is no way to enumerate them. You can only access them directly by name (so you would already have to know the names).

For resources with build action **Resource** or **Embedded Resource** you can use Ivan's solution.

The discussion to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456609/how-to-enumerate-images-included-as-content-in-the-xap) might give you a bit more code and information.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help:

```
var resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: Not enough. 
I see following string 
Microsoft.Phone.g.resources
Microsoft.Phone.Resource. resources
Microsoft.Phone.LocolizeString. resources
Where get list with attached files from?