# Windows phone 7 copy data from instalation folder to IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am building a music application in which I use 450 music samples. I have in the app package all the songs and artwork. I am trying to copy them to the IsoStorage and the to populate the DB table with the name of the files for later use.

I am doing that so later my app can receive an update periodically , but for the first use I do not want to use a web service to download the data.

```
private void InitMyStorage()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (!isf.DirectoryExists("Audio"))
        {
            isf.CreateDirectory("Audio");
        }
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("Data");// Directory in the application
        var ext = new List<String> { ".jpg", ".mp4" };
        var files = di.GetFiles().Where(f => ext.Contains(f.Extension)).ToList();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {                
           writeFile(file.Name, "Audio\\"+file.Name); // Stream writer method
        }
    }
```

The problem is that for the simulator I can see the list of files in the directory but on the device it throws an exception.

After the list of files is created I am calling the whriteFile Method like this

```
private void writeFile(string szFrom, string szTo)
    {
        Stream str = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Data/" + szFrom, UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
        if (str != null)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream isfsOutput = isf.OpenFile(szTo, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

            if (isfsOutput != null)
            {
                BinaryReader brInput = new BinaryReader(str);
                BinaryWriter bwOutput = new BinaryWriter(isfsOutput);

                for (byte[] buffer = brInput.ReadBytes(1024); buffer.Length > 0; buffer = brInput.ReadBytes(1024))
                {
                    bwOutput.Write(buffer);
                }

                bwOutput.Close();
                brInput.Close();
            }
            isfsOutput.Close();
        }
    }
```

If anyone can help please :) with why on the device I can not read the directory?

Or give me another ideea in how to implement this. ?.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer from Matt Lacey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474496/30512) which uses a static list of files to deploy which are generated by a T4 template.