# image file resources to image source in silverlight app

Tags: silverlight

I want a Listbox that lists all the images I have as resources in my app, then on selection changed the Image Source in my app is changed.

Need to:
Enumerate all the image files,
Load them into an imagesource

In WPF, I can just System.IO to grab the files from a directory, but I can't do this in silverlight.

how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that for files set as Resource or Content. It is possible for Embedded Resource (although Embedded Resource is not recommended for Silverlight. Don't think that an Image control can access them directly). See [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456609/how-to-enumerate-images-included-as-content-in-the-xap) It suggests creating such a list during build time [using T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)