# How to pick a random image

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I have recently started learning Windows phone app development with no c# knowledge, and I wanted to make an app that displays a random image on the ImageBox when the button is clicked.

How will I go about making a random image (from a list) come up every time the user presses the button?

Here is all I have so far:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Pic1.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: that seems like valid code to load a static image; what attempts have you made to change it to be random?

Comment: I have no clue... I was looking at a tutorial and was following that but the person never showed how to display a random image..

Comment: Do you mean you want to select a random image from a set of predefined images, or create an image on-the-fly with randomly filled pixels?  Or what?

Comment: Select a random image from a list of images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of images, or an image naming convention, then this is easy.

For example, if your images are named "Pic1" through "Pic10", then just use:

```
const int numberOfImages = 10;
var rand = new Random();
int imageNumber = rand.Next(numberOfImages) + 1;
string imageName = string.Format("/Images/Pic{0}.png", imageNumber);
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative));
```

Or if you have an array with the names of available images:

```
string[] imageNames = { "Pic1.png", "AnotherPic.png" };
var rand = new Random();
string imageName = imageNames[rand.Next(imageNames.Length)];
string imageName = string.Concat("/Images/", imageName);
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative));
```

**Edit**

It is more tricky than you might think to enumerate "Resource" images at runtime.  [See here for a discussion of this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7456609/1001985)

**Edit #2**

Actually, one of the answers from the above link has a nifty approach -- [use a T4 template to generate the list of images at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474496/1001985).